# Format JSON output from AWS Lambda function

Tags: python, aws-lambda

Lambda Program

```
import json
import boto3
from pprint import pprint
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    #instance = event['instanceid']
    client = boto3.client("ec2")
    status = client.describe_instance_status(InstanceIds=[
        'i-0c52lidc87f',
    ],)
    #pprint(status)
    for i in status["InstanceStatuses"]:
        print("AvailabilityZone :", i["AvailabilityZone"])
        print("InstanceId :", i["InstanceId"])
        print("InstanceState :", i["InstanceState"])
        print("InstanceStatus", i["InstanceStatus"])   
    return {
        'body': ("Instance Status :", i["InstanceState"],i["InstanceId"],i["AvailabilityZone"])
    }
```

Output

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": [
    "Instance Status :",
    {
      "Code": 16,
      "Name": "running"
    },
    "i-0c52lidc87f",
    "ca-central-1a"
  ]
}
```

I'm getting the above response from my lambda function on AWS - how can change this to readable format - just Instance ID: i-0c5e8c3c87f and Status: Running

Please help!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: not much - I tried changing the body, in the return but no luck!

Comment: doesn't look like valid json, dunno if that helps or not.

Comment: oh nevermind, I speak false - it is valid, I guess I was just confsed that there's a list there with mixed elements as the `body` composition value.

Comment: so you're looking for output as a `list` of string? or just a string with non-json data (the intention here being that a string is in the `body` field, as the direct value being assigned to)?

Comment: @rv.kvetch - i want it a string - just the instance id and status (Name) will do - I have added my lambda function to this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Youre JSON isnt formatted properly, if Instance Status is supposed to be a tuple, try:

```
return {
  "body": {
    "Instance Status":{
"InstanceState": i["InstanceState"]["Name"],
"InstanceId": i["InstanceId"],
"AvailabilityZone": i["AvailabilityZone"]
  }
}
```

Comment: now this is what I got in return

`1{
  "body": {
    "Instance Status": [
      {
        "Code": 16,
        "Name": "running"
      },
      "i-0df0a0fc571590c3e",
      "ca-central-1a"
    ]
  }
}`

Comment: Ah ok i think you should just need to reference the "Name" key from the "InstanceState". I updated the above if you want to try again